# How to handle a nullable enum type field in a protobuf3 message?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

The following are my protobuf definitions:

```
enum Foo {
   BAR = 0;
   BAZ = 1;      
}

message UpdateRequest {
  string id = 1;
  Foo foo = 2;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I need the `foo` field of the `UpdateRequest` to be nullable. However, if I don't set the value of this field then as per protobuf semantics it always ends up picking `BAR` as the default value.

Looking around, I found a couple of ways to handle this.

1. Add an additional `UNKNOWN` value in the enum and map it to `0` so that this value will be used as the default value instead of `BAR` and I can treat this value as null.

```
enum Foo {
   UNKNOWN = 0;
   BAR = 1;
   BAZ = 2;      
}
```

2. Use `oneof` construct.

However, somehow I feel that both of the above approaches are a kind of a workaround and I am not able to locate official documentation explaining the best practice to handle this case.

What is the best practice to handle this use case?

Comment: Why don't you like the first approach? For best practices you can check out:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum

or

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#enum

Comment: @SanP Thanks for those references to best practices. I ended up using the first approach only. I also noticed that there is experimental support for optional attributes, which appeared cleaner to me but unfortunately I won't be able to use that experimental feature in our production code. About the first approach one annoying thing was the scoping semantics of the enums. i.e. I have to keep in unique in the entire proto file which means I will have to use `UNKNOWN_FOO` instead of `UNKNOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the field using `hasFoo()`, while `getFoo()` will return `BAR`, `hasFoo()` should return `false`.

Comment: Protoc doesn't compile the `has` methods for enums

Answer (score 0):

Continue reading only if you do not wish to use `UNKNOWN` enum value.

Do not know if the best practice but whenever I'm sending the object itself where the value can't be null, I use the `enum` value.
And in requests (like your `UpdateRequest`) when it can be empty I'm using a `string` type instead and handle the conversion manually.

```
message Object {
  EnumProperty property = 1;

  enum EnumProperty {
    FIRST = 0;
    SECOND = 1;
    THIRD = 2;
  }
}

message ObjectUpdateRequest {
  string property = 1;
}
```